# Messages gives message not delivered warning, but recipient says they received it

Tags: iphone, messages, ios

I have an iPhone 7 running iOS 10. When I send a text message in Messages, I get a message from the application saying it has not been delivered.

Yet the recipients tell me it has been.

**Why is this?**

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this only when there are multiple addressees.  I have assumed that the message was not delivered to one of the addresses.